# How to refer to components props or to component itself in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to do the following:

```
function Form(props) {
    function SomeFunc(componentName) {
        // do something ...
    }

    return (
      <Form name="someForm" >
        <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc("Long_Name")} />
        <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc(this)} /> /* did not work */
        <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc(name)} /> /* did not work */
      </Form>
    );
}
```

I want to avoid typing in "Long_Name" several times. I could put the name into a variable, but that variable will be long, and I need to use it several times within the `<SomeComponent ... />` declaration.

I though I could pass `this` into `SomeFunc` so that I can use `.name` within the function but that did not work. I also tried just passing in `name` and that did not work either. I wish there was something like `self.name` or concept of `self` where the component can refer to its instance.

Are there ways of achieving this.

Comment: Maybe don't use functional component if you want to pass {this}. Maybe convert that component to class instead but why do you want to pass {this} anyway?

Comment: I don't get you. If you put the name into a variable and pass it as a prop to your component as `name={variable}` then you access it as props.name in that component. So problem solved?

Comment: So, I have a form for a financial product. Not some "fluffy" type form -- imagine over say 30 fields, and each field need to have a meaningful name. Something like:

<input name="FederalTaxForCrossProvincePurchase" error={resolveErrorFor("FederalTaxForCrossProvincePurchase")} ..etc />

Imagine I pull "FederalTaxForCrossProvincePurchase" into a variable. I would have to give it a meaningful name. Not var1 or something. Otherwise the code is not readable ...

Comment: I would be super cool if I can do something like:
<input name="FederalTaxForCrossProvincePurchase" error={resolveErrorFor(self.name)} ... etc />

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the *SomeFunc* **down** to the *SomeComponent* and it will have access to your component props , So, you can call the passed SomeFunc with the required props( which is what you want ... the control over the component.)

Note You cannot just use `this.propName` in the component itself, even with `class` based components. If you want to make use of `name` property you can use it as explained below.

```
function Form(props) {
    function SomeFunc(arg) {
        // do something ...
        return arg;
    }

    return (
        <form name="someForm" >
          <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc} />
          <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc} />
          <SomeComponent name="Long_Name" someProp={SomeFunc} />
        </form>
    );
}


function SomeComponent(props) {
// Your render goes here. Just see the way of using props
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>{props.name}</h1>
            {/* calling the SomeFunc with name via someProp Property */}
           <h2>{props.someProp(props.name)}</h2>
        </div>
    )
};
```

And if you want to use  ***this*** keyword you need to convert your component to *`class`* component , as there is no meaning of `this` keyword inside the functional component.

**EDIT** :

If the prop expects a certain type of value , you can always create a custom component which will wrap the native component and provide it the props values as expected.

In your case you can wrap the `<input error={ Boolean } .../>` into a component which will make sure to provide you the props as expected type.

Comment: Problem is, myVar[0] is not readable, when you have a long form (with say over 30 components). Error prone ....

Comment: I have a property called "error" (from Material UI). When I try to do <input error={someFunc} .../> I get this error: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `function` supplied to `ForwardRef(FormControl)`, expected `boolean`."

Comment: Hi Mukul, I was trying to reduce the # of characters I was trying to type in ... wrapping will work but it's still extra effort. I use standard Material UI components, and now I have to wrap them ... I think think the short answer is that there is no magic "self" variable that can refer to the component itself ...  or there is no way to declare a variable within jsx itself...

Comment: Exactly @IgorKrupin there is no such thing , and as I have already mentioned this in my answer , I was just suggesting you some methods you can  try to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a map of components and their props and render them as an array:

```
const components = new Map([
  [SomeComponent1, "Long_Name_1"],
  [SomeComponent2, "Long_Name_2"]
]);

return (
  <Form name="someForm">
    {[...components].map(([Component, name]) => (
      <Component name={name} someProp={SomeFunc(name)} />
    ))}
  </Form>
);
```

An object instead of map can also be used in the same fashion.

Comment: That's a good idea, but form is complicated (grids, rows, etc). I would have to wrap each component into a function which will spit out (per form field) the appropriate <Grid> elements as well as the component itself ....

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could at least store parts of such configuration in a map and access it when rendering components manually.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. I basically have a list of components, I just keep pulling in "next one" whenever I need it, within my grid. The order then has to matter. How would I "stuff" my map with such components? How would I add Component1 to such map? It would nee to be in a function then, right?